# 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1' and 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

I have an error compatibility with the dependencies `'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'` when I implement `'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'`

This is the code:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
}
```

Comment: well what does the error say?

Comment: use `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1`

Comment: I do not get an error to say, but it does not let me use the dependency

Comment: i try com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1 and i have the same error.

Comment: ll com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
```

Or change all these lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'

//firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'

//firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
```

More details [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

According to your comments, the following implementations are also needed:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it does not work for me. I still have a problem with "implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'"

Comment: Paste here the entire text when you put the mouse over or a screenshot of it.

Comment: ll com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 27.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

Comment: Do the exact thing that the error said. Add `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1` and `com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1` and your problem will be gone.