# Android studio Firebase dependency is not compatible with appcompat

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I'm trying to add `firebase-auth:15.0.0` dependency to my project with `appcompat-v7:27.0.0` but it causes a warning that "mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes".
I also tried to add new updated dependency of `firebase-auth:15.1.0` but it causes the same issue.

Here is my dependencies block

```gradle
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation failed to complete:Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254283/com-android-supportsupport-v427-1-1-and-com-firebaseuifirebase-ui-auth3-2/50254704#50254704).

Comment: Can you post the exact warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upgrade to Version 27.1.0 as long as you are using libraries that run on lower versions. In your case, you simply have to "give in" and go for Version 26.1.0 (the lowest common denominator). You may upgrade to Version 27.1.0 once all libraries have been upgraded to 27.1.0.

Please try

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

Comment: Didn't help me though...

but I see the same error on 

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

The error is been fixed here on this video https://youtu.be/Vjy_uv10t30

Or

add this `//noinspection GradleCompatible`

before

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

and synch.

That's all.

Comment: Please don't post links only. Always sumarize the most important parts so that your answer is also useful in case the link target is not available anymore.